# What is the "Stage" folder inside MarkLogic Installed Directory? How does MarkLogic use this folder?

Tags: marklogic-9

There is a "Stage" folder within the MarkLogic installed directory, wanted to know what is this folder about and how/when MarkLogic uses it?

I checked that the folders within the Stage directory are Config,Logs,Meters and Support. What I am not sure is what and how these folders will be used and by which process within MarkLogic,

Answer (score 2):

Stage is where Telemetry data is stored - https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/monitoring/telemetry. Note this from documentation - "*The level set for each telemetry setting affects the amount of data collected and has a small impact on storage and network use. Telemetry may use up to a maximum of 20GB of storage in the Stage directory, though typically the volume will be less than 100MB.*"